# How do I get Google+'s notifications into Android's notification list?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, google-plus

From iOS I'm used to seeing app icon badges and notifications concerning actvity inside apps. Android is lacking app icon badges but it does have a great notification menu -- except that Google+ notifications (the red counter in the black Google bar on all Google's web sites) don't arrive there. I do see the counter in the Google+ app (in Android as well as in iOS) but on Android there's no notification outside of the app.

I think it's weird that Google's awesome social network doesn't send notifications to Google's mobile OS.

I am hoping that it's merely some setting I need to enable on my phone to make these appear. Right?  I very much doubt that I really have to launch the G+ app to see notifications, given that so many other apps use Android's notification methods so successfully.

**How can I see Google+ notifications in Android's notification list?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uhhh...I get Google+ Notifications all of the time.

Check:

- `Settings | Apps | Google+ | Show Notifications` is checked
- In the Google+ app, `Overflow menu (three vertical dots) | Settings | Notifications` is ON. Tap that entry and choose which types of notifications to get. I see

  - POSTS AND MENTIONS

    - Mentions
    - Shares
    - Comments
    - Comments on a post after I commented
    - Circle subscriptions
  - CIRCLES

    - Adds me
  - PHOTOS

    - Tags me
    - Comments on a photo I am tagged in
    - Comments on a photo I tagged
    - Photos added from Instant Upload
  - EVENTS

    - Invitations or updates to events
    - Reminders about events I'm invited to
    - Activity on events I created
  - COMMUNITIES

    - Invites me to a Community

Comment: Thank you! I saw the setting "Notifications" and it was listed as `ON` so I figured they were turned on... It is never evident from these Android menus that they actually contain sub-items... I still need to learn to operate Android, it's very different from what I'm used to.